# Way to horizontally align text in different footnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

Is there any way to align text in footnotes without adding `\hspace{}` and guessing the spacing?

What I have:
[image]

What I would like to have:
[image: goal]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for SI units
\usepackage{wasysym} %for diameter symbol

\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{PTFE tube: $\diameter_{\text{inner}}=\SI{0.5}{\milli\meter}$, $\diameter_{\text{outer}}=1/16^{\prime\prime}$} and some other text\footnote{Silicone tube: $\diameter_{\text{inner}}=\SI{1}{\milli\meter}$, $\diameter_{\text{outer}}=\SI{3}{\milli\meter}$}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: It should be `\hspace{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the eqparbox package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for SI units
\usepackage{wasysym} %for diameter symbol
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{%
    \eqmakebox [A][l]{PTFE tube:} 
    \eqmakebox [B][l]{$\diameter_{\text{inner}}=\SI{0.5}{\milli\meter}$,} $\diameter_{\text{outer}}=1/16^{\prime\prime}$}
    and some other text\footnote{%
    \eqmakebox [A][l]{Silicone tube:} 
    \eqmakebox [B][l]{$\diameter_{\text{inner}}=\SI{1}{\milli\meter}$,} $\diameter_{\text{outer}}=\SI{3}{\milli\meter}$}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does indeed work! Could you please edit your answer briefly explaining what it does and how it works? Thanks

Comment: eqparbox has a quite nice manual, you can open it with `texdoc eqparbox`.

Comment: where would I type that command to get the manual? I'm using TeXstudio so I don't have any CLI

Comment: texstudio imho has a menu entry for texdoc in the help menu.

Comment: Right, thanks! Off topic, I think you meant _afaik_ (i.e. "as far as I know") and not _imho_ (i.e. "in my honest opinion").